# Lua table created in C returns strange values for integers

Tags: lua, lua-table, lua-c++-connection

I want to create a nested table, that shall look like this:

```
{
  SA_1: {1,2,3,4},
  SA_2: {11,22,33,44}
}
```

The code I have (I changed the SA_2 to strings for testing purposes):

```
int myRegisteredCfunc:
{
    lua_createtable(L, 0, 2);

    // Create the first inner table
    lua_createtable(L, 0, 4);
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; ++i) {
        lua_pushinteger(L, i);  // Push the corresponding value
        lua_rawseti(L, -2, i);  // Set the value at the index
    }
    // Set the first inner table as a field of the outer table
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "SA_1");

    // Create the second inner table
    char test_str[20];
    lua_createtable(L, 0, 4);
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; ++i) {
        sprintf(test_str, "str %d",i);
        lua_pushstring(L, test_str);  // Push the corresponding value
        lua_rawseti(L, -2, i);  // Set the value at the index
    }
    // Set the second inner table as a field of the outer table
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "SA2_2");

    return 1
}
```

However, the output I get is:

```
SA_1 (table):
  4: 3
  1: 4
  2: 3
  3: 3
SA_2 (table):
  4: str 4
  1: str 1
  2: str 2
  3: str 3
```

The values for SA_1 are not set correctly. I do get 3 times number 3, instead of 1-4.
The strange part is, the strings are actually printed correctly.

This is my print function:

```
    local table = LIB.myRegisteredCfunc() 

    local function print_table(tbl, indent)  
        indent = indent or 0  
        local spaces = string.rep("  ", indent)  
        for k, v in pairs(tbl) do  
            if type(v) == "table" then  
                print(spaces .. k .. " (table):")  
                print_table(v, indent + 1)  
            else  
                print(spaces .. k .. ": " .. tostring(v))  
            end  
        end  
    end 

    print_table(table)
```

Comment: The question is inconsistent, you first said you want `SA_2: {11,22,33,44}`, actually you got `str 1, str2...`, but you said "the strings are actually printed correctly." emm...Correctly??

Comment: @shingo yes as mentioned just for testing. To see if strings behave different as the integers. And they do work. So it seems like the overall logic is correct, but however the integers do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Lua is able to create sequence tables, but you passed the wrong parameter, the 2nd parameter is the hint of sequence capacity, so it should be:

   ```
   lua_createtable(L, 4, 0);
   ```
2. When you use `pairs` to iterate over a table, [its order is always unspecified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73741252/why-does-the-same-lua-script-have-inconsistent-execution-results/73741334#73741334).

Comment: Thanks, the order is now displayed correctly, however, the values for the table SA_1 are still incorrect.
SA_1 (table):
  1: 0  
  2: 3  
  3: 3  
  4: 3

Comment: Is this the actual code? I tried it and it printed 1,2,3,4 as expected. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Try adding `printf("%f\n", lua_tonumber(L, -1));` before `lua_rawseti`.

Comment: I updated Lua from 5.4.2 to 5.4.4 and now it works ...